# Expected value of Normal random variable and Log-Normal random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

In a text book I'm currently reading but also in Bakshi, Chao, and Chen (1997), they write that a normally distributed random variable $Y = \ln(1+X)$ has mean $\ln(1 + \mu_{X}) - \frac{1}{2}\sigma_{X}^{2}$ and variance $\sigma_{X}^{2}$, where $X$ is log-normally distributed. My question is therefore, how did they derive the mean and variance. I was first thinking of using LOTUS, but for some reason I'm not getting the right results. I would appreciate some clarity on this problem.

Comment: I don't know that book but perhaps it has a section on 'change-of-variable' technique, otherwise a quick google search will yield some information. It is useful in such a scenario.

Comment: @oliverjones The book is called 'Applications of Fourier Transform to Smile Modeling - Theory and Implementation' by Jianwei Zhu and can be found at the bottom of page 160. The other is a paper I've referenced to. Unfortunately, I cannot find a change-of-variable section.

Answer (score 1):

They used this formula:
If pdf of $X$ is $f_X(x)$ and cdf of $X$ is $F_X(x)$ and you have $Y=\ln(1+X)$, this means that:
$$F_Y(x)=F_X(e^x-1)\text{ and }f_Y(x)=e^x\cdot f_X(e^x-1)$$
If $X\sim\text{Log-Normal}(\mu,\sigma)$ this means that

$$f_X(x)={\dfrac {1}{x\sigma {\sqrt {2\pi }}}} \exp \left(-{\dfrac {\left(\ln x-\mu \right)^{2}}{2\sigma ^{2}}}\right)\text{ and }F_X(x)={\displaystyle {\frac {1}{2}}\left[1+\operatorname {erf} \left({\frac {\ln x-\mu }{\sigma {\sqrt {2}}}}\right)\right]}$$
In general if $Y=h(X)$ and $h'(x)>0$ you have that $F_Y(x)=F_X(h^{-1}(x))$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand what you have written, but I find it hard to see how they ended up with the mean of $Y$ being $\mu_{Y} = \ln(1+\mu_{X}) - \frac{1}{2}\sigma_{X}^{2}$ and the variance $\sigma_{Y} = \sigma_{X}^{2}$.

Comment: Maybe this is usefull:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Functions_of_random_variables

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it out now.